# Simple online web game crash eventually

Tags: javascript, php, server

**Background:**
I am making a simple game in PHP, JavaScript and HTML for the web. A player control movements of a box on the screen, and see others fly around with their boxes.

I have the following files, that I upload to my domain via a hosting company:

- `index.html`: a file with some buttons (eg. to start the game) and frames (for putting boxes in).
- `server.php`: PHP script that receives messages from client, performs reads/writes to a database, echoes (using `echo`) boxes from database to the client. Does not echo the box of the player the message came from.
- `database.txt`: a JSON text file containing data of players and the next free ID number. When empty it looks like this: `{"players":[], "id": 1}`. *players* contain objects with values such as ID, position and rotation.
- `script.js`: JavaScript file with script to send/receive messages, display data from messages etc. Linked to `index.html`. Moves your box.

A screenshot, two players in movement: [image]

**Problem:** The game crashes, always. Sooner or later. This is what happens:

1. Client recevies player data from `server.php`, everything is fine. This could be for 10 seconds or up to some minutes.
2. The data starts to falter, the message sometimes is *null* instead of actual data.
3. The data recevied is always *null*. The database file is now `{"players":null,"id":5}`. (The *"id"* could be any number, does not have to be 5).

Picture of data flow, printing of *players* from database. Two players. Before this screenshot lots of rows with valid data. Then as seen two *null* messages. Then after a while *null* forever.

[image]

I am not completely sure where the problem is, but I am guessing it has to do with my read/write in `server.php`. I feels like a lot of player movement makes the program more likely to crash. Also how often the program sends data affetcs.

**Code Piece 1:** This is code from `server.php`, that writes to the database. I have some sort of *semaphore* (the `flock( ... )` ) to prevent clients from reading/writing at the same time (causing errors). I have an other function, *read*, which is very similar to this. Possible problems here:

- The *semaphore* is incorrect.
- The mode for `fopen()` is incorrect. See [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php/%22PHP%20Docs%22). The mode *w* is for write. The tag *b* is for *"If you do not specify the 'b' flag when working with binary files, you may experience strange problems with your data ..."*.
- Something weird happening because I use `read()` in my writing function?

Code:

```
// Write $val to $obj in database JSON
function write($obj,$val){
   $content = read();
   $json = json_decode($content);
   $json->{$obj} = $val; // eg. $json->{'id'} = 5; 
   $myfile = fopen("database.txt", "wb") or die("Unable to open file!");
   if(flock($myfile, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)) {
     fwrite($myfile,json_encode($json));
     flock($myfile, LOCK_UN);
   }
   fclose($myfile);
```

}

**Code Piece 2:** This is my code to send data. It is called via a `setInterval()`. In `script.js`:

```
// Send message to server.php, call callback with answer
function communicate(messageFunc,callback){
  var message = messageFunc();
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      callback(this.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","server.php?msg="+message,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This is my code to receive data, in `server.php`: `$receive = $_GET["msg"]`.

**My current work of solving**
This is what I have done so far, but nothing has changed:

- Added mode *b* to `fopen()`.
- Added `flock()` to read/write functions in `server.php`.
- Much reworking on `script.js`, I would say it looks/works very clean.
- Check `memory_get_peak_usage()`, and check with the hosting company for memory limits. Should be no problem at all.
- Looked at PHP garbage collecting and `gc_enable()` (I don't know why that would change anything).
- Lots of testing, looking at the data flow.
- Crying.

**Conclusion:** Is this type of application what PHP is for? What do you think is wrong? If you want more code/info I provide. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the root of your problem:

```
$myfile = fopen("database.txt", "wb") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

Note the [behavior of the `w` open mode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) (emphasis mine):

> Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file **and truncate the file to zero length**. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

This happens **before you lock the file**.  What's happening is that between this `fopen()` call and the following `flock()` call, the file's content is zero length, and a reader is coming along during that time and reading the empty file.

Why doesn't this cause an error in PHP when you parse the empty string as JSON?  Because [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) is defective, and returns `null` when the input is not valid JSON rather than throwing an exception.  Nevermind that the string `"null"` is valid JSON -- `json_decode()` gives you no way to differentiate between the cases of valid input representing the null value and invalid input.  If `json_decode()` actually threw an exception or triggered a PHP error (don't ask me why two error-signalling mechanisms are necessary in PHP), you would have a fantastic point to start debugging to figure out why the file is empty, and you might have solved this problem by now!

... *sigh* ...

PHP's "design" gives me headaches.  But I digress.

To fix this whole problem, change the open mode to `"cb"` and [`ftruncate($myfile, 0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftruncate.php) after you successfully acquire the lock.

Note the behavior of the `c` mode, which actually specifically mentions the approach you are using (emphasis mine):

> Open the file for writing only. If the file does not exist, it is created. If it exists, **it is neither truncated (as opposed to 'w')**, nor the call to this function fails (as is the case with 'x'). The file pointer is positioned on the beginning of the file.  **This may be useful if it's desired to get an advisory lock (see `flock()`) before attempting to modify the file, as using 'w' could truncate the file before the lock was obtained** (if truncation is desired, `ftruncate()` can be used after the lock is requested).

Comment: Great answer, thank you! It seems to have solved the problem! However, I still get some *null* messages at times, although not eventually forever as before. I changed to your suggestion, added mode `c+b` in my *read*, and also moved the *unlocking* to after I close the file.

Comment: @JakeTheSnake Unlocking should fail if you `fclose()` first, since the file handle is now invalid.  Instead, consider adding an `fflush()` call before unlocking.  What's probably happening is the written data is being buffered, so there is still a window (between releasing the lock and closing the file) where the data has not yet been written to disk.  So your solution would work *if* unlocking the file after closing it worked.  Flushing the data before releasing the lock is a guaranteed solution; the data will be on disk before another process acquires the lock.

Comment: @JakeTheSnake Note that prior to PHP 5.3.2, closing a file implicitly releases any locks, so if you are using this old of a PHP version, it might work for you just because the `fclose()` call is releasing the lock anyway, and the `flock()` call to release it is failing -- but that's okay.  I would use the flush-unlock-close pattern as if you upgrade to or past PHP 5.3.2, you will experience weird lock contention problems as the lock will be held even after the file is closed.

Comment: Further note: I'd think for reading you would want mode `rb`.  `c+b` doesn't really do anything for you in the read case.  In fact, it's probably *wrong* to create the file at that point.  If the file doesn't exist in the read case, you can just fail immediately instead of creating the file and then discovering that it's empty.

Comment: Excellent, really. Also one thing I noticed, the *LOCK_NB* was probably wrong to use. I read this on PHP docs about *flock*: *"It is also possible to add LOCK_NB as a bitmask to one of the above operations **if you don't want flock() to block while locking**."* That sounds really weird, and it seems like that was the last bug to fix. It works! Big thanks again.